# jquery how to remove class from content when click on content

Tags: jquery, click

I want to remove the class`text-danger` from the heart icon when click on the icon but i do not succeed in it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.blog-like-counter').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.heart-icon').removeClass('text-danger'); // remove red color heart icon  
  });
});

<div class="blog-like-counter">
    <p class="heart-icon text-danger">&#9829;</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cp8ms2tu/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please use find method because next method is getting next element not inner element**

```
      $('.blog-like-counter').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find('.heart-icon').removeClass('text-danger'); // remove red color heart icon
      });
```

Comment: Now it works! But can you explain me why `next` could not find `heart-icon` ?

Comment: because heat-icon is .blog-like-counter inner div not next element

Comment: `.next()` gets the next sibling - you need to find a matching child-element, which you do with `.find`

Answer (score 1):

**Using the children method will solve the problem aswell**
Next gets the next element and not the next "child" element.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.blog-like-counter').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('.heart-icon').removeClass('text-danger'); // remove red color heart icon  
  });
});
```